# Why can't I copy one array to another?

Tags: c, c-strings

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char string[100];
    string = *argv[1];
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Do I actually need to use loops to iterate through each element and do everything the long way?

Comment: If you're looking for convenience, C is not the language to use.

Comment: Note: the types are different. But even `string = argv[1];`  is forbidden.

Comment: This assignment will (probably) assign the first character of `argv[1]` to first character of `string`.

Comment: The language simply doesn't allow it, so yes you have to use loops (directly or indirectly through standard functions like `strcpy`). Or, considering that the strings in `argv` will be valid and in scope for the duration of the program, just use pointers instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work?

Because that's simply how it works in C. Trying with `string = argv[1]` (without *) would be a better guess, but you cannot copy arrays with simple assignments.

> Do I actually need to use loops to iterate through each element and do everything the long way?

Unless you are prepared to use functions like `strcpy`, `strncpy` or `strdup` or something similar, then yes. Using `strncpy` in your code would look like this:

```
char string[100];
strncpy(string, argv[1], sizeof(string));
string[sizeof(string) - 1] = 0;
```

The last line is to make sure that `string` is terminated. Clunky? Yes, it is. There are better functions in some compilers like `strlcpy`, which is available on POSIX systems, but it's not a part of the C standard. If you use `strlcpy` instead of `strncpy` you can skip the last line.

If you're planing to do a lot of string copying and don't have a compiler supporting `strlcpy`, it might be a good idea to write your own implementation (good practice) or just copy an existing one. Here is one I found:

```
size_t
strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz)
{
    char *d = dst;
    const char *s = src;
    size_t n = siz;
    /* Copy as many bytes as will fit */
    if (n != 0) {
        while (--n != 0) {
            if ((*d++ = *s++) == '\0')
                break;
        }
    }

    /* Not enough room in dst, add NUL and traverse rest of src */
    if (n == 0) {
        if (siz != 0)
            *d = '\0';      /* NUL-terminate dst */
        while (*s++)
            ;
    }
    return(s - src - 1);    /* count does not include NUL */
}
```

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/brillo-m7-dev/libcutils/strlcpy.c

Comment: `strncpy` will always write `n` bytes, padding with zeros if the source string is shorter. `strlcpy` or a custom implementation thereof, which doesn't do the padding, might be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

In the main function in C `argv` is a vector to strings which are arrays of characters themself. So `argv` is a pointer to a pointer (like `**char`).

Your code assigns a reference to one pointer (to first argument).

`char* string = argv[1];` would do it. To copy the whole string (array of characters) use `strcpy`. To copy all arguments use `memcpy`.

But usually in a C program you do not copy arguments, just use references to them.

Comment: "*in C `argv` is a vector to strings*", no it is an array of **pointer** to the 1st character of a C-"string".

Comment: I wrote it from my practical knowledge, but you could find exactly my words in e.g.: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

In C, an array name is not an L-value expression. Hence you can not use it in an  assignment statement. To make a copy of a character array, you can either use a for statement or strcpy function, which is declared in string.h header file.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: because it is. In the C language only structures and unions are copied by value with one exception:

**Initialization of the array**

```
void foo(void)
{
    char x[] = "This string literal will be copied! Test it yourself";
    char z[] = "This string literal will be copied as well But because it is much loger memcpy will be used! Test it yourself";

    float y[] = {1.0,2.0, 3,0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0, 3,0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0, 3,0,4.0,5.0};

    long long w[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

    foo1(x,z); // this functions are only to prevent the variable removal
    foo2(y,w);
}
```

and the compiled code:

```
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        sub     sp, sp, #320
        mov     ip, sp
        ldr     lr, .L4
        ldr     r4, .L4+4
        ldmia   lr!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        stmia   ip!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        ldmia   lr!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        stmia   ip!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        ldmia   lr!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        stmia   ip!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        ldm     lr, {r0, r1}
        str     r0, [ip], #4
        strb    r1, [ip]
        add     r0, sp, #208
        mov     r2, #110
        ldr     r1, .L4+8
        bl      memcpy
        mov     r1, r4
        add     r0, sp, #56
        mov     r2, #72
        bl      memcpy
        mov     r2, #80
        add     r1, r4, #72
        add     r0, sp, #128
        bl      memcpy
        add     r1, sp, #208
        mov     r0, sp
        bl      foo1
        add     r1, sp, #128
        add     r0, sp, #56
        bl      foo2
        add     sp, sp, #320
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L4:
        .word   .LC2
        .word   .LANCHOR0
        .word   .LC3

.LC2:
        .ascii  "This string literal will be copied! Test it yoursel"
        .ascii  "f\000"
.LC3:
        .ascii  "This string literal will be copied as well But beca"
        .ascii  "use it is much loger memcpy will be used! Test it y"
        .ascii  "ourself\000"
```

Structures and unions are copied by the value sothe assignment copies the whole structure to another.

```
typedef struct
{
    char str[100];
}string;

string a = {.str = "This string literal will be copied before main starts"},b;

void foo3(string c)
{
    string g = a;
    b = a;

    foo4(g);
}
```

and the code:

```
foo3:
        sub     sp, sp, #16
        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
        mov     r6, #100
        sub     sp, sp, #104
        ldr     r5, .L4
        add     ip, sp, #116
        add     r4, sp, #4
        stmib   ip, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        mov     r2, r6
        mov     r1, r5
        mov     r0, r4
        bl      memcpy
        mov     r2, r6
        mov     r1, r5
        ldr     r0, .L4+4
        bl      memcpy
        add     r1, sp, #20
        mov     r2, #84
        add     r0, sp, #136
        bl      memcpy
        ldm     r4, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
        add     sp, sp, #104
        pop     {r4, r5, r6, lr}
        add     sp, sp, #16
        b       foo4
.L4:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
        .word   b
a:
        .ascii  "This string literal will be copied before main star"
        .ascii  "ts\000"
```

you can play with it yourself:

https://godbolt.org/z/lag4uL